# JQuery Tools: How to populate title tag from another JS file text string

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-tools

I am using JQuery Tools plugin for tooltip its working fine but I would like to load my text string for tool tip from another JS file or how to populate title tag from another JS file text string. Here is my code:

```
$(".show-tooltip-top[title]").tooltip({position: "top center"});
```

Previously I was doing like this with JQuery only not plugin:

```
$(".tooltip-test",this).html("This is a tooltip test");
```

Comment: You look at the answers to your questions and click the empty checkmark next to the answer that helped you the most.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you're asking, but if you just want to know how to change the `title` attribute of an element, you can use [jQuery's `attr` function](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/attr):

```
$(".show-tooltip-top[title]").attr("title", "your title text goes here").tooltip({position: "top center"});
```